# In TFS 2010 the Email alerts are not working, failure sending mail

Tags: tfs, tfs-2010

I'm using smtp4dev to send email alerts from TFS. I'm using Windows VIsta.
In TFS administration Console->Email Alert Settings, I set SMTP server as localhost and Email from Address is my mail id.
In Visual Studio 2010, Team->Project Alerts, I enabled "Anything is checked in" and gave another email id in Send to field.
After my checkins, I didn't receive any email. smtp4Dev is visible in system tray.

In Event Viewer, I found the below Error,

```
TF53010: The following error has occurred in a Team Foundation component or extension:
Date (UTC): 12/3/2012 6:07:33 AM
Machine: MACHINE112
Application Domain: TfsJobAgent.exe
Assembly: Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a; v2.0.50727
Service Host: 
Process Details:
  Process Name: TFSJobAgent
  Process Id: 2804
  Thread Id: 6996
  Account name: NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE
```

> Detailed Message: TF271001: An error occurred while attempting to send an e-mail notification to the following address: yyyy@example.com. Further e-mail notification errors that occur within the next five minutes might not be logged. Verify that the e-mail notification settings are correct in the Team Foundation Administration Console.
> Exception Message: Failure sending mail. (type SmtpException)

Answer (score 1):

Please confirm the identity of Visual Studio Team Foundation Server Background Job Agent And Team Foundation Server Web Access Application Pool in IIS.

Web Access will use the identity of this app pool to connect to Smtp Server to send mail. And if you change a workitem, the notification will be sent by Visual Stidio Team Foundation Server Background Job Agent. If the account does not have permission to connect to smtphost, you will not receive the mail.

Both services must be running under same account.